# Username retrieval from an AWS Appstream 2.0 application with SAML integration

Tags: .net, saml-2.0, aws-appstream

We are in the process of integrating SAML authentication for an application we deploy on AWS Appstream 2.0. We expected to keep receiving the original username in the `AppStream_UserName` environment variable, but we are getting an id or token. Is there any way we can use it to retrieve the original username from our application, which is a classic .NET desktop application? We are using [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as identity provider.

I'm aware of the answer in [How do I get the current user from within an AWS AppStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845018/how-do-i-get-the-current-user-from-within-an-aws-appstream), but we are likely to have tens if not hundreds of users and, if I understood the answer correctly, it would complicate user management considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the username format is not defined by either SAML or Appstream, but is in fact a Keycloak setting. The `SAML Client` configuration page has a `Name ID Format` field which may be set to either `username` or `email` to obtain a familiar value. You may need to also set the `Force Name ID Format` toggle to override request-level policies.